# ChartJS: horizontalBar Label Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm with a error on my HorizontalBar Chart. Basically when i mouse hover on some bar, it should show me the Label name and Value of this bar. But in my chart it shows Label and Label, without value.

Here is a pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGNPM.jpg
it should show me : "Top 10 Clientes and 2400 below"

This is totally static code, here is:

```
    var gerarGraficoDeBarrasHorizontal = function (name, labels, components){

    var myChart = new Chart(name, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: components
        },
        options: optionsSemLegenda
    });
}

// OBJECT TO CLARIFY THE CHART CREATION
var barrasHorizontal = [{
    data: [2500, 5000],
    backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],
    borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'],
    borderWidth: 1
}];

// CREATE CHART
gerarGraficoDeBarrasHorizontal('topDezClientesxFaturamentoTotal', ["Top 10 
Clientes", "Faturamento Total"], barrasHorizontal);
```

Thanks a lot!!

@Edit #1

```
var optionsSemLegenda = new Object();
optionsSemLegenda = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    },
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem) {
                return tooltipItem.yLabel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using version 2.5.0?

Comment: Thanks for answer, and Yes! i'm using 2.5.0.

Comment: Can you provide your actual options config?  Whatever is defined for the `optionsSemLegenda` variable

Comment: Yes! Here you are! Question edited.

Comment: What happens if `yLabel` -> `xLabel`? Next time try to supply a JSFiddle from the beginning, please. :)

Comment: Yeaahh! Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm :D ! I'm sorry, next time i will do a JSFiddle for real!